# Unable to get moment of inertia of hollow sphere right

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

I was trying to find Moment of inertia of the Hollow sphere rotating about an axis (horizontal in the figure) as in the figure below. The Moment of inertia will be the double of the value which I will get after considering only one hemisphere. Now, If I assume the thickness of the strip to be t, then the elemental area becomes $2\pi r t$.

now the elemental mass $dm = \rho*2\pi r t$ where $\rho $ is the areal mass density.

$\rho = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2} $

But from figure, $r = R*cos\theta$ and $x = Rsin\theta$

and if $d\theta = t/R$ (angle = arc/radius) $=>$ $t = Rd\theta$

Now $dm$ becomes $ dm = \rho * 2\pi * R cos\theta * Rd\theta $

$dm =  2\pi \rho R^{2} cos\theta d\theta $

[image]

Now if I bring 2 right that is spreading on both hemispheres, then

[image]

But $4\pi R^2 \rho$ is the Total mass $M$, so

[image]

But the expected answer is $\frac{2}{3}MR^2$

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: A sphere of mass $m$ has the same MMOI as a hemisphere of mass $m$ also. This is because the two objects have different densities.

Comment: Did I treat hemisphere as having mass M?, Ithink no

Comment: Dear @ja72 please see now, I have changed the doubt a little, I couldn't see where I am going wrong. please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your treatment is odd. Your band (the ring) will make sense if the axis is vertical (labeled as "X" on your figure), because it then will have great symmetry about the vertical axis. For the horizontal axis, your band does not have good symmetry so you will have difficulty integrating it. Specifically, your $dI$ does not equal to $dm x^2$ because different part of the band has different distance from the horizontal axis. For the left and right most ends, the distance is $x$ thus $dI=dmx^2$. In other places, use Pythagorean theorem to find the true distance. Again, you will have difficulty integrating it because it lacks symmetry.

Comment: Sorry if I made confusion. but I have noted in the figure itself that my x is vertical. Also I am making a correction inthe question that I have not taken thickness to be $dx$ but I have taken it as $Rd\theta$ itself. Another thing is I drew it this way  because I felt easy to imagine wgile drawing, thanks for respond